# Error with CPGN code

Tags: verilog

CLA.v

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module CLA(//CARRY LOOK AHEAD ADDER
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input [3:0] A,
    input [3:0] B,
    output [3:0] seg_an,
    output [7:0] seg_cat
    );
    
    wire [3:0] S;
    wire [3:0] P;
    wire [3:0] G;
    wire Cin;
    wire [4:0] C;
    
    
    
    bitslice dig0(
        .A(A[0]),
        .B(B[0]),
        .Cin(Cin),
        .S(S[0]),
        .P(P[0]),
        .G(G[0])
    );

    bitslice dig1(
        .A(A[1]),
        .B(B[1]),
        .Cin(Cin),
        .S(S[1]),
        .P(P[1]),
        .G(G[1])
    );

    bitslice dig2(
        .A(A[2]),
        .B(B[2]),
        .Cin(Cin),
        .S(S[2]),
        .P(P[2]),
        .G(G[2])
    );

    bitslice dig3(
        .A(A[3]),
        .B(B[3]),
        .Cin(Cin),
        .S(S[3]),
        .P(P[3]),
        .G(G[3])
    );
    
    CPGN adder(
        .G(G),
        .P(P),
        .Cin(Cin),
        .C(C)
        );

    wire clkl;
    wire Y;
    wire [3:0] I;
    wire [3:0] out;

    clk_divider clockboi(
        .clk(clk),
        .rst(rst),
        .clk_div(clk1)
        );
    
    flippyfloppoty two_bit(
        .clk(clk1),
        .Y(Y),
        .seg_an(seg_an)
        );
        
     mux input_mux(
        .Sel(Y),
        .Sum(S),
        .Cout(C),
        .I(I)
        );    
        
    sevenseg light(
        .I(I),
        .seg_cat(seg_cat)
        ); 
        
               
endmodule
```

bitslice.v

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module bitslice(
    input A,
    input B,
    input Cin,
    output S,
    output G,
    output P
    );
    
    assign S = A ^ B ^ Cin;
    assign G = A & B;
    assign P = A | B;
endmodule
```

mux.v

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module mux(
    input Sel,
    input [4:0] Cout,
    input [3:0] Sum,
    output [3:0] I
);

   assign I = Sel ? {3'b0, Cout} : Sum;
   
endmodule
```

I'm working on this code for a while and I keep running into issues with the summation part. Allow me to elaborate:

- When I perform addition such as X + X, where X is any number/bit, the result is reversed. So for example, 1(0001) + 1 = 20, 2+2 = 40, etc.
- My other problem is that some of the math is off. I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong, but can't tell what's wrong with the code and I can't seem to find the issue.

Any ideas would be great, please. Thank you!

Additionally, I'm working on a device where A and B refer to switches.

Comment: Why don't you use the simulation to debug? That is much, much more effective than trying to debug someone else's long code that has no comments and cryptic identifiers. flippityfloppoty? seg_an? seg_cat?

Comment: The math problem is obvious: you have the `Cin` port of each `bitslice` connected to the same `Cin` signal, rather than to the individual `C[i]` bits generated by `CPGN`.

Comment: @DaveTweed Bless you. That was the issue. I'm learning to program this and I couldn't comprehend what was going on behind the scenes. Or I did on paper but not on code. Thank you very much! You are awesome. I'll update the post for anyone who has a question similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code section to repair the math issue: The issue was that all of the bitslice would add the following 1 + 1, 0 + 0,etc. depending on a set of switches. The problem is say we were adding 1 + 1. The result would be 10 in binary, but we can only grab 1 bit and send the other bit over. The old code wasn't sending the carry over correctly. Thanks to @DaveTweed I was able to find the error in my work and understand this code better. Below is the updated code and the CPGN module is added to see what CPGN is doing to C and how it is sending it over.

'''
bitslice dig0(
.A(A[0]),
.B(B[0]),
.Cin(C[0]),//Here
.S(S[0]),
.P(P[0]),
.G(G[0])
);

```
bitslice dig1(
    .A(A[1]),
    .B(B[1]),
    .Cin(C[1]),//Here
    .S(S[1]),
    .P(P[1]),
    .G(G[1])
);

bitslice dig2(
    .A(A[2]),
    .B(B[2]),
    .Cin(C[2]),//Here
    .S(S[2]),
    .P(P[2]),
    .G(G[2])
);

bitslice dig3(
    .A(A[3]),
    .B(B[3]),
    .Cin(C[3]),//Here
    .S(S[3]),
    .P(P[3]),
    .G(G[3])
);

CPGN adder(
    .G(G),
    .P(P),
    .Cin(Cin),
    .C(C)
    );
```

'''

CPGN MODULE

'''
module CPGN(
input [3:0] G,
input [3:0] P,
input Cin,
output [4:0] C
);

```
assign C[0] = Cin;
assign C[1] = (C[0] & P[0]) | G[0];
assign C[2] = (C[1] & P[1]) | G[1];
assign C[3] = (C[2] & P[2]) | G[2];
assign C[4] = (C[3] & P[3]) | G[3];
```

endmodule
'''

Comment: Is this supposed to be a final solution?  If so, please "accept" it after the self-answer timer expires.  But if this is only progress and an issue remains, this needs to be an *edit* to your question and not an "answer".

Comment: Yes, it is. But it's asking that I wait until tomorrow to accept the answer.

Comment: Well, do that then :-)   In the meantime you could make it a bit more clear that this is the resolution by using the edit button to explain that, in particular to explain what exactly the fix accomplishes.  Things that *look like* mis-use of the answer form to ask questions tend to get flagged.

Comment: Of course. I'll have it edited sometime today. Thanks again to this StackExchange. Usually I get snotty answers on other websites, but you guys have been super helpful.